# Get height of Iframe and the resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I need to get the height of the iframe . And also i need to get a resize event so that i could change the height dynamicaly when the iframe loaded content changes. Till now am success in getting the height but no resize event.

```
    $("iframeID").load(function(){
    $("iframeID").height($("iframeID").contents().find("body").height());
      $("iframeID").resize(function(){
       //this doesn't fire up
      });
   });
```

Comment: Can you resize your iframe? Don't you want to fire on the resize of the browser not the element? `$( window ).resize(function() { //code }`

Comment: What will cause the iframe to get resized in the first place? Did you try triggering the resize after the handler is created to test if it works inside iframe? What are your expectations for this code with regard to parent page/window

Comment: Actually am loading a part of application to that iframe. When clicking on that part resize the iframe. I need to get the height when that happens. So that i could set the height to the iframe. The reason is am using custom scroller. and need to set the correct height to the iframe

Comment: and also it's not possible to add any code inside the page am loading.

Comment: If you can't add code on your iframe, you won't be able to trigger a resize event from the iframe, to your parent document. Due to cross Frame policy. With that beeying said, iframes tend to be static in their dimensions and this is a known problem for many years.

Comment: @TimVermaelen could be same domain though and OP isn't allowed to modify the page or app itself. OP already able to get iFrame access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to get the height from the iframe content on resize. You really need access to the child page. I found [this](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) on really helpfull.But you need to include iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js fil in child page and it will work like charm. I have used it and it worked my like charm for me.